# Install k9s on Ubuntu WSL on Windows 11

Tags: 22.04

I want to install k9s on Ubuntu WSL on Windows 11.

When I try to install it I get an error that snapd is down:

```
➜  ~ sudo snap install k9s
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/k9s: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

When I start snapd I get a new error:

```
➜  ~ systemctl start snapd.service
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Anyone know how I shoudl proceed?

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with WSL2, you can fix it by running this :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -yqq daemonize dbus-user-session fontconfig
sudo daemonize /usr/bin/unshare --fork --pid --mount-proc /lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=basic.target
exec sudo nsenter -t $(pidof systemd) -a su - $LOGNAME

snap version
```

Source : https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5126#issuecomment-653715201